# Synchronous database queries or database collection locking using Donet core and MongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I came across the challenge of implementing a sequencer. This sequencer fetches the latest record, increments a field value, and saves it as a new record after incrementing.

the challenge here is while I fetch, take the required field value, increment, and save a new record, there is a chance of another record getting inserted through some other request.

To avoid this Is there any feature or concept in dotnet core to handle locks on the database table?
I use dotnet core - mongo Db for storing the data through the entity framework code first approach.
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at how to solve concurrency conflicts in EF Core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations).

Some other scenarios come to mind:

**1. Basic Locking**

Just put all the code in the `Increment()` function in a `lock` statement. It should look something like this:

```cs
private readonly object DbLock = new();

void Increment()
{
    lock(DbLock)
    {
    // Fetch from database
    // Increment
    // Update record
    }
}
```

I am using the word "basic" because locking comes with it's own set of problems that you might have to deal with such as deadlocks or lock contention.

**2. Interlocked**

`Interlocked` is a class that allows you to increment and update values "atomically". Quote from the [Interlocked documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-5.0):

> On most computers, incrementing a variable is not an atomic operation, requiring the > following steps:
>
> Load a value from an instance variable into a register.
>
> Increment or decrement the value.
>
> Store the value in the instance variable.
>
> If you do not use Increment and Decrement, a thread can be preempted after executing >the first two steps. Another thread can then execute all three steps. When the first >thread resumes execution, it overwrites the value in the instance variable, and the >effect of the increment or decrement performed by the second thread is lost.

In this case, you can use `Interlocked.Increment` to increment a variable that you got from the database and then create a new record with it.

**3. ConcurrentDictionary**

This works like a normal `Dictionary` that uses fine-grained locking to perform operations. This might not be what you are looking for though. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-remove-items) is the documentation. Also, take a look at [thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I wanted to clarify a doubt regarding Basic Locking. Will this work for Scoped type repository instance? Will it work if two parallel requests reach this method, one continues with the transaction and the other requests wait till the lock is released? any prerequisites i have to take care of?

Comment: @SaiTejaSingamsetty Everything you need to know about the [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement). Please elaborate a bit on the "Scoped type repository instance".

Comment: So the repository layer in the app has Scoped lifetime - for every new request there is a new repository object. For two different requests, which will resolve into two different repo objects, will this lock statement still be able to handle is what I was asking?

Comment: @SaiTejaSingamsetty Create a singleton service that provides access to this lock. Inject that service into both classes. You should be fine. In my opinion, if you have multiple scopes that update elements in a database (there are no issues with concurrent reads) you should handle your database access with a singleton service layer.